# Succinct word for a definition

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms

I’m looking for a word in English that describes “to use oneself against oneself.”

The closest word I can think of is “entrapment” but that’s not quite it.

Comment: It would help to have an example of what you're considering as “to use oneself against oneself” in the context of the question.

Comment: As this question lacks an example sentence or context, I am voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know in English. Depending on the context, one of these might help:
self-betrayal, self-mutilation, self-scorn, self-destruction, self-denying (or the corresponding verbs).

In Romanian, "automutilare" refers to physical harm,
or ("automutilare" + "emotionala") which expresses an emotional damage.
We also use `self-sabotage` (auto-sabotare).

Comment: You might want to include [self-destruct (verb)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-destruct) in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may well mean **self-recrimination**:

> *self-recrimination*: the act of accusing or blaming oneself
>
> - … a story whose own identity slips from the slow burn of an erotic thriller to a far deeper, more wrenching study of parental loss,
>   self-recrimination and grief. — Ann Hornaday
> - All of the past year's regrets and self-recriminations came rushing back: the sleepless nights, the anguished days. — Justin Peters

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-recrimination)]

You sometimes hear 'Stop beating yourself up' when people are wallowing in self-recrimination.